# retrieve title text from img class

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I try to retrieve an image title from a class but only get the following error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

The source looks like this:

```
> <span class="serien-heute-terminblock"><span class="img-wrap"><img
> title="ARD-alpha" alt="ARD-alpha"
> src="https://bilder.fernsehserien.de/logos/svg/10.svg"></span>heute</span>
```

I have tried the following 2 approaches but neither works:

```
for sender in doc.findALL("span", {"class":"serien-heute-terminblock"}):
    sender_titel = sender.getText("img title")
    print(sender_titel)
```

and

```
for sender in doc.findALL("span", {"class":"img-wrap"}):
    sender_titel = sender.getText("img title")
    print(sender_titel)
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_all` or `findAll` instead of `findALL`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example = """
<span class="serien-heute-terminblock"><span class="img-wrap">
<img title="ARD-alpha" alt="ARD-alpha 
src="https://bilder.fernsehserien.de/logos/svg/10.svg"></span>heute</span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(example, "lxml")

for sender in soup.find_all("span", {"class":"serien-heute-terminblock"}):
    sender_titel = sender.find("img")
    if sender_titel is not None:
        print (sender_titel["title"])
```

> ARD-alpha